# Would a group of molecules in a container, settle down after a long time? (considering that no gravity acts on them)

Tags: thermodynamics, electromagnetic-radiation, collision, kinetic-theory

Because, every time they collide, don't they emit radiation? As in, losing energy in the form of this radiation,
So eventually, won't they lose all of their kinetic energy? Of course the time taken might be very long

Comment: Why would they emit radiation?

Comment: Because after a collision, one of the particle gets accelerated to a higher speed, and accelerating charges emit radiation. But, are these collisions elastic?

Comment: Collisions at molecular level are always taken to be elastic.

Comment: Is your container at absolute zero temperature?

Comment: @my2cts no, actually, I thought that the collisions are inelastic. But turns out, they're not. So that solves the doubt

Comment: In my fridge often thing settle down, but on my oven they cook. Is your container a fridge or an oven? Or is it at room temperature?

Comment: @sammygerbil It almost does, because she has mentioned that they lose energy (which I expected​), but she hasn't mentioned that they would eventually settle down and stay at rest. Would they? Because their only forms of energy are the kinetic energy and the energy in the bonds, isn't it? And when they keep losing this, wouldn't​ they eventually come to rest?